# The size and scale of Plotly graph integrated in Shiny dashboard would change when maximizing screen

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am integrating a plotly graph in Shiny dashboard. However, the size and scale of the graph would change to after maximizing screen or drag the UI to a screen with different resolution.

Blow is the screenshot of the graph I want:

[image]

Blow is the screenshot of the graph after maximizing the screen:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

)

body <- dashboardBody(
  box(title = "Test",
      plotlyOutput("plot")
      )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = b1image$CNT, y = b1image$Label, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h', 
            marker = list(color = viridis::viridis_pal(option = "C", direction =1)(max(b1image$Label) - min(b1image$Label) + 3)))  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The data I used to plot is from the dataframe named b1image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

)

body <- dashboardBody(
  box(title = "Test", width = 10, height = "500px",
      plotlyOutput("plot",width = "400px", height = "400px")
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

      output$plot <- renderPlotly({


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, x=a, y=b, z=c, mode="markers", type="scatter3d", marker = list(size = 5, color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'))
p <- layout(p, scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "A",range = c(-2,2)), yaxis = list(title = "B",range = c(-2,2)), zaxis = list(title = "C",range = c(-2,2))))
    p

      })
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)

      })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


 box(title = "Test", width = 10, height = "500px",
      plotlyOutput("plot",width = "400px", height = "400px")
  )
```

1. Define you box width and height
2. Define your ploty width and height

   `p <- layout(p, scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "A",range = c(-2,2)), yaxis = list(title = "B",range = c(-2,2)), zaxis = list(title = "C",range = c(-2,2))))`
3. Define your plotly range of axis